# slf4 logging day wise log from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j

I am using sl4j configuration in spring boots application.properties with single log file logging.log , how can i create a daily log file with name of the file as the current date.

```
 logging.level.root= INFO
 logging.level.org.springframework.web= ERROR
 logging.file = logging.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest solution is to make a logback.xml file in the resource folder.

And config the file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/logs" />

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>
            ${DEV_HOME}/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<logger name="ar.com" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</logger>

<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
</root>
```

I found this information in: 
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-slf4j-logging-example/